# Android Gallery only showing three pictures

Tags: android, android-view, android-gallery

Pic of app here: http://imgur.com/6A92Yl6

So I have a gallery set up that upon a click-through allows the user to select a picture from the view and then see the picture and their corresponding toast with it.

The problem is that there are only THREE images that pop up. I don't know why and theres no variable that limits the gallery so I am at a loss for words.

My main:

```
public class MainActivity<View> extends Activity 
{

 ImageView selectedImage;  
 private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.image1,
            R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3,
            R.drawable.image4,
            R.drawable.image5,
            R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7,
            R.drawable.image8,
            R.drawable.image9,
            R.drawable.image10
    };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    selectedImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    gallery.setSpacing(1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "THIS TEXT SHOULD NEVER SHOW = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // show the selected Image
            selectedImage.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Picture Number: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // show the selected Image
            selectedImage.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);

        }
    });
}
}
```

---

MY XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.13"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have not used your list to populate it with adapter. Show the implementation of Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to populate the adapter with mImageIds when creating the new GalleryImageAdapter.

Comment: There were three thumbnails there already. How do I populate the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Adapter:

1. Change call of adapter to:

   gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this, mImageIds));
2. Add/Update **GalleryImageAdapter.java:**

   ```
   import java.util.List;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.Gallery;
   import android.widget.ImageView;

   public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private Activity context;

   private static ImageView imageView;

   private List<Drawable> plotsImages;

   private static ViewHolder holder;

   public GalleryImageAdapter(Activity context, List<Drawable> plotsImages) {

   this.context = context;
   this.plotsImages = plotsImages;

   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return plotsImages.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     if (convertView == null) {

       holder = new ViewHolder();

       imageView = new ImageView(this.context);

       imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

       convertView = imageView;

       holder.imageView = imageView;

       convertView.setTag(holder);

   } else {

       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(plotsImages.get(position));

   holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
   holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 90));

   return imageView;
   }

   private static class ViewHolder {
       ImageView imageView;
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(plotsImages.get(position)); It says that ".setImageDrawable in the imageview type is not applicable for the argument"

Comment: Since you are using integer ids and not the resources directly so **instead of using setImageDrawable use setImageResource**.   i.e. use **imageview.setImageResource(plotsImages.get(position));**

Comment: I can get the gallery to pop up with all ten images in the thumbnail browser, but it crashes upon going to the 4th pic.

Comment: could you add three things  1. error log  2. your device/emulator configuration 3. image properties(size)

Comment: Anil, thanks anyway but somehow the code is working now. Not sure what I changed.